# Body in basketball

Tags: basketball

We know that in basketball you can only use the hands to play the ball, but what if

1. a player unintentionally touches the ball with his torso and then
   he catches the ball on fly?
2. same situation but a player
   intentionally touches or bobbles the ball on his torso?
3. a player
   unintentionally touches ball with leg and then he catches the ball
   on fly?

Comment: What kind of ruleset are you talking here - FIBA, NBA, NCAA?

Answer (score 1):

Here are my thoughts...

For scenario(s):

1. A torso catch is quite common. The problem is catching and not getting whistled for a moving violation.
2. A torso bobble and catch is also common. There is no violation as long as control is not established while moving. A player can bobble catch and take two steps with a violation.
3. Unintentional leg/foot contact is allowed. You can literally hit the knee of a defensive player and score a basket, as long as the defender did not intentionally use the knee (trying to block a bounce pass).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).